# Issue testing if inner function is called using Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

The function I'm trying to test is below. We are using a builder like approach for assembling our complicated URL structures to help with navigating around our web application.

```js
import { useNavigation } from '../../../blah';

useNavigation().goBack();
```

The full-function I'm trying to check was called is below

```js
export const useNavigation = (path) => {
  const { view } = store.getState();

  const withQueryParams = (params = {}) => {
    const paramString = addQueryStringParameters(params);
    return useNavigation(`${path}${paramString}`);
  };

  const tlo = (id) => useNavigation(`/${id}/${id}${path}`);

  const site = (id) => useNavigation(`/${view.activeTLO.id}/${id}${path}`);

  const current = () => useNavigation(`/${view.activeTLO.id}/${view.activeSite.id}${path}`);

  const navigate = () => history.push(path);

  const goBack = () => history.goBack();

  return {
    withQueryParams,
    tlo,
    site,
    current,
    navigate,
    path,
    goBack,
  };
};
```

In Jest, I'm trying to mock the internal goBack function so that we can check if it's called at a certain point in the code, but I'm having no luck so far.

I'm importing and mocking the function like so

```js
import * as navigateTo from '../../../lib/navigateTo';

navigateTo.useNavigation = jest.fn(() => ({
  goBack: jest.fn(),
}));
```

When trying to do the expect on the goBack function, to check if it was called things get a little odd.

The below expect does work as it can see that navigateTo.useNavigation has been called but with every effort, I cannot check if the navigateTo.useNavigation.goBack has been called as it's always undefined.

```js
it('renders the navigate to the orders page', () => {
  const actions = availableOrderActions(settings).find((action) => action.label === 'Supplier Orders');
  actions.clickHandler();

  expect(navigateTo.useNavigation).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the way you would mock out this sort of thing.

```js
import * as navigateTo from '../../../lib/navigateTo';

const goBack = jest.fn();
navigateTo.useNavigation = jest.fn(() => ({
  goBack,
}));

it('renders the navigate to orders page', () => {
   const actions = availableOrderActions(settings).find((action) => action.label === 'Buyer Orders');
   actions.clickHandler();
   expect(navigateTo.useNavigation).toHaveBeenCalled();
   expect(goBack).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```